# Criteria for $L^1$ convergence looking at Laplace transforms

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, laplace-transform

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a sequence of integrable ($\mathbb{E} |X_n| < \infty$) random variables  and denote by $l_n(t)$ the Laplace transforms of $X_n$. Similarly, let $X$ be a r.v. and $l(t)$ its Laplace transform.

It is known (Levy continuity theorem for Laplace transforms) that $l_n(t) \to l(t)$ for every $t>0$ iff $X_n \Longrightarrow X$ (where with the notation $X_n \Longrightarrow X$ I mean that $X_n$ converges weakly/in distribution to $X$).

Denote by $g'$ the first derivative of $g$. I was wondering whether additional hypotheses such $l_n'(t) \to l'(t)$ for every $t>0$ (or maybe simply $l'_n(0) \to l(0)'$) imply that $X_n \stackrel{L^1}{\to} X$.

Comment: there is never any necessary relation between convergence in distribution and $\mathbb L^1$ convergence.  E.g., the r.v.'s convergeing in distribution may not even be defined on the same  probability space, or, e.g., i.i.d. normals are constant in distribution but don't converge in .....  On the other hand, if you also have something like pt-wise convergence, existence of a laplace transform in the nbhd of zero is a very strong condition.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question to think about. I came across it from the following problem:
pointwise convergence of Laplace transform implies weak convergence of probability measures $\mathbb{P}_n \xrightarrow{w} \mathbb{P}$. Is there anyproperty on Laplace transform so probabilities converge in total variation norm?
$$
  \sup\limits_{A\in \mathbb{B}(R)}|\mathbb{P}_n(A) - \mathbb{P}(A)| \rightarrow 0
$$

There is an interesting result about characteristic functions on this topic (look for Van der Vaart, Asymptotic Statistics, Cambridge Univ. Press):

Theorem: Consider $Y_1,\dots, Y_n$ -- i.i.d r.v. with $\mathbb{E}Y = 0, \, \mathbb{E}Y^2 < +\infty$. And let characteristic function $\phi(t)$ satisfies the following
$$
 \int |\phi(t)|^\nu dt < \infty, \text{ for some } \nu \geq 1,
$$
then 
$$
\dfrac{Y_1 + \dots + Y_n}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{TV} \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$

Remark: Total variation -- is equal to $L^1$ distance between densities, so this property implies $L^1$ -- convergence. Proof is following from Sheffe corollary

Corollary (Sheffe): Consider $\{p_n\}$, p -- densities wit respect to dominating measure $\mu$. If $p_n\rightarrow p$ $\mu$ -- almost everywhere then random values $X_n \xrightarrow{TV} X$, where $X_n$ have density $p_n$ correspondingly and $X$ has density $p$.

Conclusion:
I still think on it, but if I want to use Sheffe corollary to investigate the problem for Laplace, I have to study the inverse Laplace transform. If through it you can show almost everywhere convergence of densities -- then you will have an $L^1$ type of convergence.

$\textbf{Another solution}:$ Thanks to nice talk with professor Yuri Davydov from Paris 6 Univ. there is a link to the nice property of Laplace-Stiltjes transform related to strong convergence (convergence in $L^1$ for densities):

Kovács, Mihály, and Frank Neubrander. "On the inverse Laplace-Stieltjes transform of A-stable rational functions." New Zealand J. Math 36 (2007): 41-56.